# What is the difference between data model and data structure?

Tags: data-structures, datamodel

I am new to databases. I studied "Introduction to databases" in my first semester and came across different types of data models (relational, network,...). This semester we are studying data structure and algorithms.

What is the difference between data model and data structure? I know their definitions but i wanna know how they are different from each other?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more specific in your question? Can you describe where you already see differences and what exactly you want to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational, Network etc are types of database management systems.  A database management system or DBMS is a software system that uses a standard method of cataloging, retrieving, and running queries on data. Oracle and MySQL are examples of DBMS.

A data structure is an abstraction that allows you to manipulate data in your program. Examples of data structures would be Arrays , Linked Lists and Binary Trees